# WIN2003 DNS/WINS Decommission

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2003, wins

I've been tasked with the decommission of two DNS/Wins servers in on our old site (site02). I am evaluating the servers currently from site01. The office where these servers live is moving to another site. The new site (site03) has DNS servers in place.

DC01 is mainly a DHCP server for desktops and will be left up until the last user leaves then switched off.

DC02 is complicated as all our servers in site01 point to it statically, I have completed a script to point the servers to the new DNS servers in site03.

I'm concerned about some DNS/WINS dependencies I might have missed, I am going to start running MS network monitor to try and see if there is any DNS requests on the servers.

I've also noted the scavanging was never enabled on DC01 or DC02.

Would clearing out scavanging and enabling help with this investigation into what dependencies use these servers, is there anyway to view the records of querys if I enable scavanging by the default 7 days, and will they be readable i.e. have an ip address or hostname.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't bother with Network Monitor, the DNS server can do its own detailed logging which will prove much easier to work with. For your situation I'd enable it as below:
[image]

You can then examine the log file to determine which clients are still querying the server, reconfigure them, examine the log again. Repeat until nothing is being logged anymore.

Comment: Thank you, for the machines that could be currently switched off, is there a way to point them to the new DNS servers (Like a CNAME)

Comment: No. A DNS client needs to be told where its nameservers are either by you statically configuring these, or by being told what IPs to use by a DHCP server. If the clients that are off are DHCP clients, then as long as you update your DHCP scope/s they will be fine. If they are statically configured then you'll have to reconfigure them at some point.